# Reconocer una variable de jQuery en Angular8 (con TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular8

Estoy usando Angular 8 y estoy tratando de hacer que una variable que la uso en un jQuery me la reconozca typescript o viceversa.

El código que muestro funciona bien me trae y muestra los datos por consola, pero el valor de esa variable solo la reconoce dentro de código jQuery no puedo pasarla a una variable typescript porque tampoco me la reconoce dentro de jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectPickerPacientes').on('changed.bs.select', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, prev) {
    //console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
    console.log($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    this.paciente = $(this).find('option').eq(clickedIndex).data("paciente");
    console.log('Paciente : ', this.paciente.direccionDomicilio);
  });
});
```

He buscado en Internet, pero no encuentro algo específico que me ayude con mi problema, alguien que me oriente cómo.

Comment: es raro que tengas codigo jQuery en Angular 8 probablemente estas copiando un efecto mi recomendacion es que ese efecto lo hagas con Angular 8 sin embargo lo que quieres hacer puedes usar localStorage y en Angular un Suscribe para ver si la variable cambia, no he probado esto pero deberia funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el scope, cada funcion tiene su propio ambito y su propia variable this.

Aunque no es problema el que uses jQuery sino como lo usas

1. Usa menos jQuery, deja de utilizarlo para cosas triviales y tontas que no lo necesitan, solo te complicas la vida.
2. Utiliza mas ES6 o superior, particularmente las funciones de flecha, te ahorraran problemas con los scope de las funcioens

Una funcion de flecha no crea su propia variable this, por lo que puedes seguir accediendo a la que crea Angular, un ejemplo de como quedaria una funcion jQuery pero con funcion de flecha

```
// document ready se va no sirve para nada en este caso
$('body').on('.otroElemento', ({ currentTarget }) => {
  console.log($(currentTarget).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Y como te dije anteriormente, no deberias usar jQuery para algo tan trivial, en vanilla seria asi

```
const elementoX = document.querySelector('.otroElemento');

elementoX.addEventListener('change', ({ currentTarget }) => {
  const item = currentTarget.options[currentTarget.selectedIndex];
  console.log('currentTarget.value: ', item.getAttribute('data-xn'));
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió tu respuesta ya solucioné el problema puse las fechas en las funciones y con eso lo solucioné

Answer (score 0):

El problema seguramente esté por el ámbito de la variable, es decir, que una variable definida en angular como this.mivariable no está pudiendo ser accedida desde la función ejecutada por el callback ready.
Prueba a cambiar las funciones function() por arrow functions.